# MS Access report fails to total correctly

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a report in MS Access 2010 that had been working fine for a while. I had to make updates to the report to allow the run-time selection of one or more 'reasons' that would be included on the report.

My initial process dynamically built them into the report filter at run-time, but my totals came out wrong. I then dynamically altered the QueryDef.SQL (adding the final two `AND` statements in the code below) that the report is based on, but they still came out wrong. I then discovered (did I mention that I'm not the one who originally wrote the report) that the total field is based on another query entirely.

> Quick background before everyone questions the sanity: We're calculating an audit score. Each audit is checked on several questions, most of which receive a Yes/No (pass/fail) answer. Some questions may receive a 'Total Fail' which results in a zero score for the entire audit, not just for the particular question. The individual audit score is percentage right OR zero if there is a 'Total Fail'. The overall score on the report is the average of the individual audit scores.

So, with that background, I would hope that there is enough information to make sense of the queries.

This is the query (`qryRptAtt`) that the report is based on:

```
SELECT vwAttorneys.CurrentAttorneyName AS PayeeID, tblAuditAtt.AttAudit_ID,
       vwAttorneys.CurrentAttorneyName AS Attorney_Name, tblAuditAtt.Loan,
       tblAuditAtt_A.A_ID, tblAuditAtt_Q.Question, tblAuditAtt_A.Answer,
       tblAuditAtt_A.Comment, tblAuditAtt.EndDate, tblAuditAtt.Status,
       tblAuditAttLoans.State, tblAuditAtt.Reason
  FROM tblAuditAttLoans RIGHT JOIN ((vwAttorneys INNER JOIN tblAuditAtt ON
       vwAttorneys.PayeeID = tblAuditAtt.PayeeID) INNER JOIN (tblAuditAtt_Q 
       INNER JOIN tblAuditAtt_A ON tblAuditAtt_Q.A_ID = tblAuditAtt_A.A_ID) ON
       tblAuditAtt.AttAudit_ID = tblAuditAtt_A.AttAudit_ID) ON
       tblAuditAttLoans.LoanNumber = tblAuditAtt.Loan
 WHERE (((tblAuditAtt_A.Answer)<>"NA") 
   And ((tblAuditAtt.EndDate) Between Forms!frmRptAtt!txtFrom And Forms!frmRptAtt!txtTo) 
   And ((tblAuditAtt.Status)="Submitted"))
   AND tblAuditAtt.Reason in ('reason1', 'Reason 2', 'Reason 3', 'Reason 4', 'Reason 5')  
   AND tblAuditAtt.PayeeID = '<removed for privacy>' 
ORDER BY vwAttorneys.Attorney_Name, tblAuditAttLoans.State, tblAuditAtt.Loan, tblAuditAtt_A.A_ID
```

(All the horrendous parenthesis come from Access building the query from the visual designer. Yes, there are some columns selected twice - I will clean that up if possible.)

This query is correctly giving me all the detail information I need on the report. In the report itself, the overall score field in the footer section of the report has `Control Source` set to `=IIf([txtA_TF]=0,DAvg("[Score]","[qryRptAttAggregateAudits]"),0)`. This is the one that is giving me the wrong answer. `qryRptAttAggregateAudits` is as follows:

```
SELECT qryRptAtt.PayeeID, qryRptAtt.AttAudit_ID, qryRptAtt.Loan,
       Sum(IIf(Answer="Yes",1,0)) AS Yes,
       Sum(IIf(Answer="No",1,0)) AS [No],
       Sum(IIf(Answer="DC",1,0)) AS DC,
       Sum(IIf(Answer="TF",1,0)) AS TF,
       IIf(DC>0,0,IIf(TF>0,0,Sum(IIf(Answer="Yes",1,0))/(Sum(IIf(Answer="Yes",1,0))+Sum(IIf(Answer="No",1,0))))) AS Score
  FROM qryRptAtt
 WHERE (((qryRptAtt.PayeeID)=[Forms]![frmRptAtt]![cmbAttorney]))
   AND qryRptAtt.Reason in ('Reason1', 'Reason2', 'Reason3', 'Reason4', 'Reason5')
   AND qryRptAtt.PayeeID = '<removed for privacy>'
 GROUP BY qryRptAtt.PayeeID, qryRptAtt.AttAudit_ID, qryRptAtt.Loan
```

The report total query selects from the report detail query `qryRptAtt`. In both queries, `Forms!frmRptAtt` is open and has had the appropriate fields filled with valid data.

I've tried the total query with both `(((qryRptAtt.PayeeID)=[Forms]![frmRptAtt]![cmbAttorney]))` and `AND qryRptAtt.PayeeID = '<removed for privacy>'` in the WHERE clause, with only one and with only the other (They both resolve to the same criteria, so it's really just redundant code & will be cleaned up once I get the major issue resolved).

I've exported the report to Excel and manually calculated the score there, and the report is showing a total that is about 0.6% off.

If anyone was able to follow this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: how does it work if you don't do the score calc in the same query as the other sums?i.e. don't do those if statements twice.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're after, @Brad. I ended up replacing `(((qryRptAtt.PayeeID)=[Forms]![frmRptAtt]![cmbAttorney]))` with `1=1` simply as a place holder, since it's the only non-dynamic part of the `WHERE` clause.  I've got it mostly working now, by replacing the form references in the 1st query with the actual dates from the form. Access seems to like it better that way. Once I get this fully working, I'll post back with an answer, instead of a comment

Comment: I meant make everything you have there one query except `IIf(DC>0,0,IIf(TF>0,0,Sum(IIf(Answer="Yes",1,0))/(Sum(IIf(Answer="Yes",1,0))+Sum(IIf(Answer="No",1,0))))) AS Score` then do that calc in a second query to be sure you have it right. that way you don't need to repeat all those `IF` statements.

Comment: Ah, I understand you now. Makes sense, except... That's the way the report was written previously, and it was working just fine before. I have updated my code to replace the two references in 1st query `qryRptAtt` to the date fields on the form with `#` delimited dates, and now I seem to get the correct percentage calculated. Unfortunately, the report now shows `#Error` in Total Score field. I know I'm getting the right %, because when stepping through code, I let it make all the code changes, then run the 2nd query & get the right info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was an oddity in the report definition.

The 2nd query was being used to generate rows of data that were being totaled with DAvg() in the report. The DAvg() function worked on a query result before I made my changes, but didn't seem to want to work with the query after I made the changes.

I modified the 2nd query to build a temporary table, then modified the DAvg() call in the report to reference the table instead of the query, and that seems to have it working.